# Memory error when trying to copy struct that returned from a function, to a struct that is inside an array

Tags: c

createPerson() returns struct, person is a pointer to an array of person 
struct pointers, (personNode**). trying to copy the return of 
createPerson() to personNode[x], memory error.

```
people[length - 1]->age = createPerson(name, age)->age;
strcpy(people[length - 1]->name, createPerson(name, age)->name);
```

```
typedef struct personNode
{
    char name[20];
    int age;
    struct personNode* next;
}personNode;

personNode* createPerson(char name[], int age)
{
    personNode* person = (personNode*)malloc(sizeof(personNode));

    strcpy(person->name, name);
    person->age = age;

    return person;
}

  void addPerson(personNode** people, int length)
{
int i = 0;
    int age = 0;
    char* name = 0;

    people = (personNode**)realloc(people, sizeof(personNode*) * length + 1);
    name = (char*)realloc(name, 20);
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets(name, 20, stdin);
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;
    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    getchar();
    people[length - 1]->age = createPerson(name, age)->age;
    strcpy(people[length - 1]->name, createPerson(name, age)->name);
```

Expected non crashing, got crashing.

Comment: Please can you correctly format the code (indentation, missing curly brace).
It is hard to read/understand the code.

Comment: You're missing a [mre].  How are you calling `addPerson`?  When you realloc memory for `people` within `addPerson`, you're only changing the local variable named `people`.  You never pass the new memory block outside of `addPerson`, leaking the memory and causing problems when you try to access memory that you're expecting to be allocated but is not.

Comment: This is a linked list, why do you `realloc(people...`? `createPerson(...)` allocates the node. Do NOT cast the return of `realloc` (or `malloc` or `calloc`) it is unnecessary.